# Ошибка при добавлении RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment, activity, recyclerview

Помогите пожалуйста
Вылетает ошибка Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
В строке
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.res);

Класс адаптера

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<CoinList> coinList;

DataAdapter(MainActivity context, List<CoinList> coinList) {
    this.coinList = coinList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from((Context) context);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CoinList coinL = coinList.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(coinL.getName());
    holder.priseView.setText(coinL.getPrise());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return coinList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final TextView nameView, priseView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        priseView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prise);
    }
}
}
```

класс списка

```
вpublic class CoinList {
private String name;
private String prise;
//private Image image;

public CoinList(String name,String prise)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.prise = prise;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPrise() {
    return prise;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPrise(String prise) {
    this.prise = prise;
}
}
```

Активити

```
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.res);
 adapter = new DataAdapter(this, coinLists);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Приложите код xml и где инициализируете RecyclerView

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка в том, что в вашем xml `R.id.res` является `LinearLayout`-ом. А вам нужен `RecyclerView`.